# Can a variable be used as an index number in C#?

Tags: c#, indexing

I am still learning C#, but the title basically sums it up. I tried to make a system where the user would input a number from 0 to 6, and the program would return the corresponding day of the week. I made an array of strings with all the days in them, and tried to index directly from the user input(after converting to int).

```
string[] days = { "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"};

Console.Write("Day number: ");
int num = Convert.ToInt32(Console.Read());
Console.WriteLine(days[num]);

Console.ReadLine();
```

As soon as I enter a number in the console, System.IndexOutOfRangeException shows up but the program doesn't terminate. I don't know if it is a mess up somewhere else in the code or just that variables cannot be used as index number.

Comment: Yes, you can use variables as array indexes. What happens if you change `Console.WriteLine(days[num]);` to `Console.WriteLine(num);` ? Do you get the index you expect?

Comment: This converts the character value (which is 48 for `'0'`) so you're getting out of range exceptions. Try `int num = Convert.ToInt(32(Console.Read()) - '0'`

Comment: You should debug so you can see what is happening, debugging is an important skill for a developer

Comment: Print the value of `num` using `Console.WriteLine(num)`. You will see your problem.

Answer (score 3):

[From MSDN:](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.read?view=netcore-3.1)

> `Console.Read()`: Reads the next **character** from the standard input stream.

When you enter any numeric value to the Console, `Console.Read()` converts to its unicode value.

Let's consider you entered 1 to the console,

```
int num = Convert.ToInt32(Console.Read());
           //  +               + This converts '1' to its unicode value i.e "49" 
           //  + This will convert "49" to its integer value i.e 49
```

Now your `num`  contains 49 instead of 1 and when you try to access array element with `num` as index it search for 49 instead of 1. Here you get `System.IndexOutOfRangeException` error

```
    int num = Convert.ToInt32(Console.Read());  //You entered 1, but 49 get stored in num
    Console.WriteLine(days[num]); //days[num] = days[49] (IndexOutOfRangeException)
```

---

To fix this issue, either use [`Console.ReadLine()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.readline?view=netcore-3.1) or convert unicode value to its original value

Using `Console.ReadLine()`:

```
...
int num = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
Console.WriteLine(days[num]);
...
```

Alternate way,

```
...
int num = Console.Read() - '0';
Console.WriteLine(days[num]);
...
```

Comment: Nitpick: it is not the ASCII value, but the Unicode value (which are identical up to #127)

Answer (score 0):

For short: Simply change `Console.Read()` to `Console.ReadLine()`

```
Console.Write("Day number: ");
Console.WriteLine(Console.ReadLine());
```

For explanation:
`Read()` will read the next `character` from the standard input stream. Then return an `int` of the character. So that why when you give `'0'` it would return `48` which is representative of `'0'` in `ASCII Table`

[image]

[image]

Whereas `ReadLine()` will read it as string value. From this result we are easy to convert by using `Convert.ToInt32()`

[image]

The question is whether we could use `Read()` only?

Yes. We subtract input number to `48` (or `'0'`) then we could get exactly. But it will be restricted that only 0-9 range are accepted. Thus, using ReadLine() is the best.

```
Console.Write("Day number: ");
Console.WriteLine(Console.Read() - '0');
```

Answer (score 0):

what you need to do is to replace **Read()** By **ReadLine()**

```
string[] days = { "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"};

Console.Write("Day number: ");
int num = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
Console.WriteLine(days[num]);

Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: you will find an answer here https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/difference-between-console-read-and-console-readline-in-c-sharp/#:~:text=The%20only%20difference%20between%20the,from%20the%20standard%20output%20device.

Comment: when you use Read() you get  the first character in ascii code otherwise when you use ReadLine() you get your number as an int

Answer (score 0):

What happens is that your `Console.Read` already returns an `int`, specifically the ASCII character code of the character you typed. Since the ASCII character code of `'0'` is `48` your value range is not `0` - `6` as you expect but `48` - `54`. Another thing to note is that, since we get an `int` already we can remove the `Convert.ToInt32` and we can just take the code of the character we read and substract the value of `0`:

```
int num = Console.Read() - '0';
```